# Best way to spell a made up word so that it is pronounced like the real word it's based on

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics, brands

In a situation where you want to turn a real English word like "tracker" into a made up word (eg. for business or website name purpose), is there a preferred way of spelling it to ensure readers understand and pronounce it as you intended?

For example, instead of using a the word "tracker", which of the following would be preferred if either?

- tracka
- trackka

Or another example would be "clicker":

- clika
- clikka

Is there any difference in English language between single or double 'k' in terms of the phonetic pronunciation of words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple consonants signal that the vowel that precedes them is short. So, with "clika", a person might think it's supposed to be pronounced with a long `i`, as there is only one consonant between `i` and `a`. This is more relevant with "clika" versus "clikka"; in "tracka", there is are already two consonants, so doubling is not necessary. Doubling could make the reader think that it applies to both syllables; "clicker" is often pronounced as "cli-ker", but "clikker" suggest "clik-ker". If you want both the vowel to be clearly perceived as short, and the consonant to belong only to the second syllable, this can be accomplished by including the letter `h`: "clihka".

Also, in rhotic accents, the last "r" in "tracker" is pronounced, so "tracka" would not be perceived as be suggesting the same pronunciation as "tracker".

Comment: When you say a person may pronounce "clika" with a long `i`, do you mean that they might say it like "cli-ka" as in rhyming with "fly-ka"?

Comment: @BriDavison: yes, exactly

Comment: @BriDavison I was thinking more "clee-ka", but "cly-ka" is also a possibility.